# Django - Best approach for managing 2+ types of users

Tags: django, django-users

There will be 2+ different types of users in my project, each with their own custom fields and permissions.  Since I'm not changing the method of authentication, I plan to use the default User and create profile models.

My question is, is it better to create a singular profile model, containing all the custom fields for each user type, and display the appropriate ones for each user (see method 1 below)?  Or is it better to create a separate profile model for each user type (see method 2)?

---

**Method 1**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, ...)

    usertype1_customfield1 = models.CharField(...)
    usertype1_customfield2 = models.CharField(...)
    ...

    usertype2_customfield1 = models.CharField(...)
    usertype2_customfield2 = models.CharField(...)
    ...

    # and so on for each user type...
```

---

**Method 2**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class ProfileUserOne(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, ...)

    customfield1 = models.CharField(...)
    customfield2 = models.CharField(...)
    ...

class ProfileUserTwo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, ...)

    customfield1 = models.CharField(...)
    customfield2 = models.CharField(...)
    ...

 # and so on for each user type...
```

Answer (score 0):

Method 2 is preferable as it allows you to isolate the logic of each profile to its own class. If you are concerned about repeating common fields such as `user = models.OneToOneField(User, ...)` then you could first declare some sort of `BaseProfile` for your app, and then subclass that further.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class BaseProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, ...)

class ProfileUserOne(BaseProfile):

    customfield1 = models.CharField(...)
    customfield2 = models.CharField(...)
    ...

class ProfileUserTwo(BaseProfile):

    customfield1 = models.CharField(...)
    customfield2 = models.CharField(...)
    ...

 # and so on for each user type...
```